# One liner for __future__ imports?

Tags: python, python-3.x, migration, python-2.x

We are having `__future__` imports at the top of our code like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Is it possible to have a one-liner for this, so that it is easier to maintain a common list which can be used across all the files?

I tried moving this to a file and importing it as `from FuturizePatch import *`, but it doesn't work as expected. Is there a "macros" concept in Python to achieve this?

Comment: :) We have other imports in `FuturizePatch` package, only `__future__` lines are  not applying.